# Need help For building Testing Framework

Tags: java, testing, groovy, frameworks

Recently I was trying to build a framework like TestNG but struck at Launcher thing(I don't know whether it is Launcher problem or Something else just guessing). So this is what I did.

1. First I created a Custom annotation named Test
2. Wrote a implementation class of test annotation with main method(right now I am targeting only one annotation)
3. In main method of implementation class i wrote code to read xml(so that i can get the class name and using reflection I am checking the method of the class with Test annotation and invoking it).
4. Now I wrote another class with method having test annotation and mentioned the class name in the xml file. Now when we use `testng` we get option of running that method/class as *TestNG*.
5. But in my case I don't know how to run my Class because there is no main method.
6. So I am Struck at this Point. Please suggest what I should do. If we need Launcher then please tell how we create launcher or any tutuorial/Book/weblink which contains information about Launcher.

*Note: I know if we use annotation we don't need XML file. But for Simplifying thing I am getting class name from XML later I will discard XML.

Thanks in Advance .

This is My Test Annoatation

package com.annoatation;

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Test {

}
```

This is my Class Where I am Using Annaotation:

```
package com.annoatation;

public class TestExample{
    @Test
    public void sampleMethod()
     {
        System.out.println("This is sample method");
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleMethod1()
    {
            System.out.println("This is sample method 1");
    }

}
```

This is my Main Class :

```
package com.annoatation;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestExample example=new TestExample();
        Method[] method=example.getClass().getMethods();
        for(Method methods:method)
        {
            Test test=methods.getAnnotation(com.annoatation.Test.class);
            if(test!=null)
            {
                try {
                    methods.invoke(example);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
       }

    }

}
```

I want when i Click on Run as on My TestExample Class it should Automatically invoke the main Method of main Class.
I am not sure what we say this thing in java (May be Entry point)

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to create an instance of your class and invoke the annotated method:

```
Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
object = classDefinition.newInstance();

Method method = classDefinition.getMethod("methodName");
method.invoke(object);
```